# Sage 1000 data dictionary

Tags: database, dictionary, sage

I'm just starting doing reporting using MSQL SSRS against a Sage 1000 database.  It's working well but I'm trying to find out more about the data model on the database in order to make best use of the data.

Can anyone point me to a Sage 1000 Data Dictionary that details the tables and fields and typical uses of them?  I've had a hunt around the web but I haven't been able to find anything.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to Sage 1000.

Thanks in advance.